# Cannot query tables from sheets in BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to use BigQuery inside python to query a table that is generated via a sheet:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Prepare connexion and query
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project="my_project")

query = """
    select * from `table-from-sheets`
"""
df = bigquery_client.query(query).to_dataframe()
```

I can usually do queries to BigQuery tables, but now I am getting the following error:

```
Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.
```

What do I need to do to access drive from python?

Is there another way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the scopes for the credentials. I'm pasting the code snippet from the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#python).

In addition, do not forget to give at least VIEWER access to the Service Account in the Google sheet.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import google.auth

# Create credentials with Drive & BigQuery API scopes.
# Both APIs must be enabled for your project before running this code.
credentials, project = google.auth.default(
    scopes=[
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
    ]
)

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)
```