# Unable to Query External BigQuery Tables

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

When trying to query a view that access an external table backed by Google Sheets, I am getting this error. `googleapi: Error 403: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials., accessDenied`

I have requested the scope for Drive, is there anything else I missed?

```
    client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, "projectID", option.WithScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot query tables from sheets in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68358458/cannot-query-tables-from-sheets-in-bigquery)

Answer (score 2):

Make certain that the user, or service account, which is running the query, has been granted [sufficient permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#Google_Drive_permissions) to read the Google Sheet.

Comment: Okay, how do you grant the Oauth roles to the service account, I cant see, to find that.