# Querying from a combined bigQuery table in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api, google-apps-script-api

On my Google Sheet I have a code that I use to:

- Pull an employees information from a BigQuery table
- Add it to a 'Notes' tab on the sheets file
- Then another part of the code adds an import range formula at the last row of the 'notes' tab to pull more information from a separate Google Sheet

I am trying to cut out the need for the second part of the formula and my idea was to make a second BigQuery table using the separate Google Sheet with the additional info as the source, then query each table through either a saved view of both tables or just query each table and input data separately.

The issue that I am running into is that whenever I try to run the new query I am hit with this error whenever it involves the Google Sheets table:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.

I have tried querying a saved view that combines both tables and I have tried querying just the second Google Sheets sourced table but both give me the same error. I run into no errors when I query only the original BigQuery table. My guess is it that I have to add in some sort of google drive/sheets/bigquery credentials into my code to make it work but I am not sure where to start and my google-fu hasnt turned up anything useful so far

Here is the code I use to the info, its pretty standard and that I want to say it's pulled straight from [Google's Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) with the only change being adding an 'employee' variable which is determined on the sheet and changes which associate to query for:

```js
function loadEmployee() {
  // Clear sheet
  var clearSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Notes').getRange("A2:M");
  clearSpreadsheet.clearContent();

 

  // Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
  // Cloud Platform project.
  var projectId = 'xxxxx';
  
  
  // Sets Employee Variable to query
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var name = ss.getSheetByName("Gold Belt Dashboard");
  var range = name.getRange("a1");
  var cell = range.getCell(1,1);
  var employee = cell.getValue();

  



  /* Begin BigQuery Section */
  // bigQuery DML goes here
  var request = {
    query: 'SELECT * from project.dataset.combined_table where eid = '+employee+' order by date desc',
    useLegacySql: false
  };
  
  // Make Query and get jobId
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }

  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }

  if (rows) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Notes');

    // Append the headers.
    var headers = queryResults.schema.fields.map(function(field) {
      return field.name;
    });
    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    var data = new Array(rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].f;
      data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
    }
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(data);


  } else {
    Logger.log('No rows returned.');
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably related to permissions. It looks like the authorized user lacks permission to create the BigQuery table that refers to the Google Sheet. You may want to give the user proper permissions and try running your code again.

If you are using a saved query, you may also be able to remove the credentials and go back to using a simple query. That way the table is not being built by code and the error will be cleared.

Comment: sorry the table has already been setup beforehand, not being created in the moment by the code. The user is me who created the table so I would think that I should have the proper permissions, though I will want others to be able to do it as well so I will have to figure that out as well.

When I have searched for it, I didn't find anything related to sheets/appsScript but when I saw a similar python problem, the solution was to add scope/credentials so I am hoping theres some kind of JS equivalent. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68358458/cannot-query-tables-from-sheets-in-bigquery

Comment: @DanneParedes I had a similar problem and was able to set the scopes in AppScript through the `appscript.json` file. If you can't see it in AppScript's editor go to `Project Settings` (gear icon) and check `Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor`. Then add `oAuthScopes` to the file as suggested here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest. Most likley you will need the BigQuery and Drive scopes.